# Does the normal approximation get better as a density becomes more peaked?

Tags: normal-distribution, density-function, normality-assumption, approximation

I have a sequence of densities $f_n(x_n)$, of random variables $X_n$, with means $\mu = 0$ and variances decreasing with $n$:

$$
\sigma^{2}(X_n) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}.
$$

I am approximating $f_n(X)$ using a normal approximation $N(0, \frac{\sigma^2}{n})$.

I would like to check if the normal approximation is getting better as $n$ increases. My intuition was that, given that $f_n(x_n)$ gets more and more peaked as the variance decreases, it becomes more "quadratic-like" so that the normal approximation should become more accurate (is some sense).

I tried to verify this in several ways, by using several criterions (relative error, KL distance etc..) to check if the approximation gets better, but I have failed so far. My suspicion is that this is probably wrong, so maybe somebody
can point out to me why the approximation doesn't improve.
Thanks

Note: $X_n$ are not sample averages, so the CLT doesn't apply.

Comment: This question lacks the information needed to answer it: what precisely are the $f_n$?

Comment: You've left out the information that we'd really need to give you any decent assistance, as @whuber suggests. How are we to guess what you're trying to do? Are you dealing with quantiles, maybe?

Comment: Also can you more clearly explain what you mean by 'peaked' - typically this is a reference to what usually happens when kurtosis is large, and then, if anything, normality tends to come in more *slowly*, since you won't have large kurtosis and normality at the same time.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. For example, I have in mind a r.v. $X$, with unknown density $f(X)$. Then I consider the sequence $X_n = X/\sqrt{n}$, for $n = 1, 2, \dots$. The densities of these random variables are becoming more peaked in the sense that they are converging to a Dirac mass. I wanted to verify if a normal approximation to these densities gets better as the $n$ increase. The answer is probably no (unless I make some assumptions of $f_n$) because the shape of $f_n$ doesn't necessarily get more "normal" as the variance decreases.

Comment: "*I wanted to verify if a normal approximation to these densities gets better as the n increase.*" -- thanks for the clarification. The answer is -- no, the distribution shape is unchanged by dividing by a constant.